I am a small independent inventor. How can I monetize my patent after obtaining it?
I have a granted patent, and its PCT application is active, allowing for international and subsequent applications. What are the suitable methods for patent monetization?
1.By seeking corporate partnerships myself, but many companies seem to lack channels for commercializing patents, or they may not want to pay royalties to independent inventors.
2.By collaborating with patent management agencies, but I am unsure about their credibility and transparency. Some claim to conduct public auctions, but I am uncertain if these are genuine; others operate through negotiations, but it is unclear whether the profits are transparent. Are there any recommended agencies?
3.By working with NPE (Non-Practicing Entity) agencies, although the patent monetization process might take a long time, I would prefer my patent’s technology to be manufactured and applied rather than just used for claims.
Additionally, are there any books on patent monetization that you could recommend?

First step might be an honest evaluation of the economic value of the invention. Sort of thing a venture capitalist might do. Otherwise how do you know what to ask for in royalties?

This might be something for the person buying my patent to assess? My own evaluation might not be convincing.

You still need an evaluation or else you have no way of knowing how good a deal is. Of course the other party will do their due diligence.

I understand what you mean, thank you. But I have another idea, which is to share profits based on a percentage of the revenue, rather than something like a one-time transaction gamble. Is this idea feasible?

Yes that is feasible. Be warned that you should try to get a percentage of gross revenue not net. It’s too easy to play accounting tricks on net earnings.

Thank you for your response; your insights are very important.

You left out one option - starting a company to manufacture a successful product based on your invention.
One way to add value to your patent short of commercializing it yourself is to make some progress towards developing a product based upon it. You might make a prototype or engage engineers to do a feasibly/cost to manufacture analysis.
If you have a bundle of patents that involve a specific technology a specialist patent broker would be worth looking into.
I highly recommend Steven Key’s One Simple Idea. His other books are - Sell Your Ideas With or Without a Patent | Become a Professional Inventor | Licensing Ideas using LinkedIn
I have had him as a speaker at a local inventors club and I found him genuinely interested in helping inventors.

Thank you for your constructive insights. From my personal perspective, as an inventor, I am more interested in identifying problems and creating non-obvious solutions, rather than in roles related to entrepreneurship or project management. Could you recommend a patent broker? Or how could I go about finding startups to collaborate with? I will make sure to read the books by Stephen Key.

I retired as a patent agent several years ago and do not have any current contacts. I assume you are in the U.S. If so I would look for a local inventors club to be able to share information with people in your situation.

Thank you for your prompt and sincere responses.I haven't made any specific decisions yet, but I will ask for your help if needed.
